# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in node js

Tags: node.js

I started setting up a node app but it prompt me this

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `('
'/app.js: line 1: `var http = require("http");
```

this is my code for app.js

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

can anyone help me in this

Comment: not sure if this is exactly the issue, but you need to put the second http in quotes, so: `var http = require("http");`. You also probably want to change that 300 in `.listen` to 8080

Comment: @HenryWoody again it gave me same error

Comment: With that updated code, it works fine for me, did you try copy & pasting straight from here?

Comment: @HenryWoody yes i tried copy & pasting, and i also have https for my server

Answer (score 8):

This is probably because you are running your script as if it is a bash script.
You have two options

1. run your program with the command `$ node your_pgm.js`
2. add the line `#!/path/to/node` to the beginning of your program (it must be the very first line)

Comment: Tip: To find the path to the current node you can use the command `which node`.

Comment: I was trying to run a shell script under `spawn`of `child_process` and gettings similar error when I use `shopt` within it. (All other commands work fine). Inspired by this reply I did prepend the command with `#!/bin/bash` and somehow it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you typing in bash?

Please try to type "$ node" first and then you should see:
Welcome to Node.js v14 (or any version that you have installed).

Comment: I tried your code on my setup and it is working fine